# Second line indent office js

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

I know, There is a way to indent the first line ONLY. Also, indent the entire paragraph beside the first line. What I'm looking to do is to indent the 2nd line ONLY, to the length of the first word in the first line.
I thought to use office js. but I can't manage to count and cut lines.

[image: Second line indent]

Comment: What code have you tried so far?